# C++, WINAPI Почему не создаются файлы txt_copy, или создаются но не все?

Tags: c++, winapi

Запускаю приложение, и оно то вообще не создает файлы, то создает в случайном количестве их.
Не могу понять ошибку, подскажите, пожалуйста)

```
void WriteFiles(size_t i);

DWORD WINAPI WriteToFiles(LPVOID lp)
{
    DWORD pr = GetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess());
    SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS);
    SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL);

    HWND hMutex = (HWND)lp;

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("..\\30.04.20 Mutex\\count.txt");
    if (!fin.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Count File has not been opened!\n";
        return TRUE;
    }

    char count[256];

    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        fin.getline(count, 256);
    }
    fin.close();

    size_t amount = atoi(count);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, NULL);
        WriteFiles(i);
        ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
    }

    SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), pr);

    return FALSE;
}

int main()
{
    SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS);
    SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL);

    HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, TEXT("{6B8DCE2A-B6A7-47B2-8EFF-9F120C7CE2C9}"));
    if (hMutex == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Mutex has not been created!\n";
    }

    HANDLE hWriteThread = CreateThread(0, 0, WriteToFiles, hMutex, 0, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hWriteThread);
    CloseHandle(hMutex);


    return 0;
}

void WriteFiles(size_t i)
{
    string name;
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;

    fin.open("..\\30.04.20 Mutex\\txt.txt");
    if (!fin.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Txt.txt File has not been opened!\n";
        return;
    }

    name = ("..\\30.04.20 Mutex\\");
    name += ("txt_copy") + to_string(i + 1) + (".txt");
    fout.open(name);
    if (!fout.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File has not been opened!\n";
        return;
    }
    fout << fin.rdbuf();
    name.clear();
    fout.close();
    fin.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-моему, проблема в том, что вы не даете потоку нормально поработать, сразу закрываете и завершаете программу. Что он успевает - то вы и получаете.

```
HANDLE hWriteThread = CreateThread(0, 0, WriteToFiles, hMutex, 0, NULL);
CloseHandle(hWriteThread)
```

Comment: Уже разобрался, у меня родительский процесс (Windows приложение) создавал процес этот (консольное приложение). И в main стоит в конце return 0;
Оно просто не успевало все выполнить, добавил system("pause") и все работает)
Спасибо за помощь))